# reversing a doubled linked list without using any extra pointer

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

im trying to reverse a double linked list without using any extra pointer.I only have head pointer pointing to the first node of my double linked list.

here is my function to reverse the linked list:

```
int reverse(){
if(head==NULL || head->next==NULL){
    return 0;
}
else{
    head->prev=head->next;
    head->next=NULL;
    head->prev->prev=head->prev->next;
    head->prev->next=head;
    head=head->prev;
    while(head->prev==NULL){
        head->prev->prev=head->prev->next;
        head->prev->next=head;
        head=head->prev;
    }
}}
```

if my linked list have data 1,2,3,4,5 and after running the reverse function ,when i'm trying to display the data i'm getting output: 2,1 (instead of 5,4,3,2,1)

Comment: What is your question? Have you run this in a debugger or even stepped through it with pen and paper? That's the correct way to try and understand what the program is doing and what the errors may be.

Comment: `if(head==NULL && head->next==NULL)` That will cause a NULL pointer access when `head` is a NULL. You probably want `||` instead of `&&` there.

Comment: Why not just iterate over your list swapping `next` and `prev` and when you are done, swap `head` and `tail`?

Comment: Why the "without using any extra pointer" restriction?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think the challenge is doing that without using any extra pointers. Not sure whether that is a hard requirement or something OP thinks is a good idea for some reason.

Comment: You could always use the XOR hack to swap and follow the `prev` pointer afterwards to iterate.

Comment: This function will not compile!  amongst other things,  `head` is not defined and the `else` body is lacking a `return value` statement

Comment: @user3629249 i defined `head` in structure the only error i have ,is in while statement `while(head->prev==NULL)` after correcting the error my program compile and works fine

Comment: Since the struct is not defined in the posted code, we have no idea about the specific details.  You should have posted code that includes all critical details

Answer (score 0):

there is a error in while statement `while(head->prev==NULL)` 
the correct code is `while(head->prev!=NULL)`

so the correct code of the function is:

```
int reverse(){
if(head==NULL || head->next==NULL){
    return 0;
}
else{
    head->prev=head->next;
    head->next=NULL;
    head->prev->prev=head->prev->next;
    head->prev->next=head;
    head=head->prev;
    while(head->prev!=NULL){
        head->prev->prev=head->prev->next;
        head->prev->next=head;
        head=head->prev;
    }
}}
```